# Is Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory for making Owin auth middleware that uses AD?

Tags: security, active-directory, owin

I'm trying to understand the purpose of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` and can't seem to find any documentation, tests, or even [much](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/12/10/protecting-a-self-hosted-api-with-microsoft-owin-security-activedirectory) in the way of articles.

What is this package actually for? I was trying to use it to create middlewear that authenticates against active directory and just can't seem to trace through what the parameters for `UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication` actually do nor how to use them to point at my own AD server.

What's going on with this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer from [my codeplex issue](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/291)

> That package primarily works with Azure Active Directory (AAD) and
>   Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) via WsFederation. We don't
>   have any support for LDAP, but some 3rd parties may. Here's one
>   example: https://auth0.com/authenticate/aspnet-owin/active-directory
>
> Contributions for new auth middleware are best directed here:
>   https://github.com/owin-middleware

Still nothing on how to actually use it or when though.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the ADFS extension for securing WebAPIs http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/.
We use it to secure our APIs either via ADFS or Azure AD

Answer (score -2):

Here is the most comprehensive writeup:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/12/10/protecting-a-self-hosted-api-with-microsoft-owin-security-activedirectory/

Comment: I am aware of this article and in fact have it linked as a part of my question. [As I responded on the codeplex issue I created](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/291) this article isn't much of a resource. Surely you don't mean to imply that the most comprehensive writeup of this library is a single paragraph on a small aspect of it in an article about something else altogether.